# Problem with hair cards

Tags: materials, objects, light, transparency

When I stack the hair cards side by side, the places where the textures overlap turn black.
I needs advice or suggestions on how to fix this problem. :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is probably due to the shadow mode in the materials setting. Use alpha clip or hashed. For hair it could be set to none as well... just try it out.

Comment: @Jackdaw, honestly I don't know what I should change, maybe can you give me more information :)

Comment: Please reopen this.  It's clearly unrelated to cycles. 
The setting it in the material properties tab.
Also, when submitting questions please make it easier to give a correct answer by uploading the file as well. I'm not sure that this is the problem.